# Laravel 5 Form Request Blank Screen Error on DigitalOcean

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-form

I'm creating a contact form in Laravel 5. The contact form is on homepage and when a user fills it out then clicks the submit button, laravel sends the email using mandrill and just refreshes the page. The code works perfectly on my Local environment. However on digital ocean droplet when a user clicks the submit button, domain.com/contact route is being triggered and I can only see a blank page.

Here is my controller

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\ContactFormRequest;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContactController extends Controller {

public function create() {

    return view('forms.contact');

}

public function store(ContactFormRequest $request) {

\Mail::send('emails.contact',
    array(
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'email' => $request->get('email'),
        'user_message' => $request->get('message')
    ), function($message)
{
    $message->from('info@pbl-landing.com');
    $message->to('muhammetergenc@gmail.com', 'Admin')->subject('Contact Request');
});

 return \Redirect::route('index')->with('message', 'Thanks for contacting us!');

}

}
```

Here is my routes.php file

```
Route::get('/',
['as'=>'index', 'uses'=>'WelcomeController@index']);

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

 Route::controllers([
'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
 ]);

 Route::get('contact', 
 ['as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'ContactController@create']);
 Route::post('contact', 
 ['as' => 'contact_store', 'uses' => 'ContactController@store']);
```

Comment: Check your logs for errors, both for Laravel (in `storage/logs`) and the server logs (not sure about your setup & which logs to check - start looking in `/var/log`). I would suspect an authentication issue or some other problem connecting to mandrill.

Comment: There was a permission issue on my images directory. I fixed it then the contact form started working just fine.  @Kryten